# Imacros javascript If file (A) not found, delete file (B)

Tags: javascript, file, firefox, imacros

If file **A** exist, break the code.

if the file **A** doesn't exist, delete **B** file

My code keeps deleting the **B** file, it does not matter if the file **A** is present..

```
iimSet("file",f);
var  f = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile); file.initWithPath("C:\\A.txt"); 

if (f == 1) { 
// file exists 
iimPlay("CODE:WAIT SECONDS=3")
} else { 
// file doesn't exist 
if (f != 0)

var g = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile); file.initWithPath("C:\\B.txt"); 
file.remove(true);
break;    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using something like this:

```
if (iimPlay("CODE:SET !DATASOURCE C:\\A.txt") == 1) {
    // file exists 
    iimPlay("CODE:WAIT SECONDS=3");
} else {
    // file doesn't exist 
    iimPlay("CODE:FILEDELETE NAME=C:\\B.txt");
}
```